# How to mock method which is called multiple times c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a common method which is being called multiple times(around 30-35 references in the project). This method is basically fetching data from DB into data table.

Following is the testable code:

```
public class MyApp
{
   private readonly IDataProvider _dbProvider;
   public MyApp(IDataProvider dbProvider)
   {
       _dbProvider = dbProvider;
   }

   public void Process()
   {
       string query = "something";
       Helper h = new Helper(_dbProvider);
       // This method will be called in the Process method several times
       var data = h.GetData(query);
   }
}

public interface IDataProvider 
{
   IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString);
   DataTable FillDatatableFromAdapter(IDbCommand command);
}

public class DataProvider  : IDataProvider 
{
     public IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
     {
         return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     }

     public DataTable FillDatatableFromAdapter(IDbCommand command)
     {
          DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
          SqlCommand sqlCommand = command as SqlCommand;
          using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
          {
              sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
          }

          if (dataSet.Tables.Count == 0)
              return null;

          return dataSet.Tables[0];
     }
}

public class Helper
{
   private readonly IDataProvider _dbProvider;
   public Helper(IDataProvider dbProvider)
   {
       _dbProvider = dbProvider;
   }

   public DataTable GetData(string query)
   { 
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       using (IDbConnection connection = 
       _databaseProvider.CreateConnection(_connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
           {
               command.CommandText = query;
               command.Connection = connection;
               table = _dbProvider.FillDatatableFromAdapter(command);
           }
       }
       return table;
    }   
}
```

I have mocked DB classes to not hit DB from unit tests.
Following is the test case code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMyApp()
{
     Mock<IDbCommand> mockDbCommand = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
     Mock<IDbConnection> mockDbConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
     Mock<IDataProvider> mockDatabaseProvider = new Mock<IDataProvider();

     mockDbConnection.Setup(m => m.CreateCommand()).Returns(mockDbCommand.Object);
     mockDatabaseProvider.Setup(m => m.CreateConnection(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockDbConnection.Object);

     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     mockDatabaseProvider.SetupSequence(mock => mock.FillDatatableFromAdapter(It.IsAny<IDbCommand>()))
                                .Returns(dataTable);

     MyApp app = new MyApp(mockDatabaseProvider.Object);
     app.Process();
   //  And then after that I am testing some data.
}
```

I will be calling GetData() method several times and therefore FillDatatableFromAdapter will also be called several times. As in the above test case I have mocked FillDatatableFromAdapter method and I am returning some fake data table for further testing.
I am aware of SetupSequence method in Moq which I can use to return multiple data tables from the mocked method everytime that method is called.

I want a suggestion is that approach correct because then I will have to create that many number of Data tables which will be return from the mocked method using SetupSequence? Or is there some other better approach?

Any help??

Comment: Does it work as is?

Comment: Yes it is working but then I am creating multiple data tables to return.

Comment: Shouldn´t your `Helper` class implement a interface, too? As this is the main dependency from your `MyApp` class (Helper wraps `IDataProvider`). Then you should mock the `Helper` class in your tests, since you want to test the logic of the `MyApp` class currently

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what you want to test.
A small refactoring will help you better test your code

```
    public class MyApp
    {
       private readonly IDataProvider _dbProvider;
       private readonly IHelper _h;
       public MyApp(IDataProvider dbProvider)
       {
           _dbProvider = dbProvider;
           _h = new Helper(_dbProvider);
       }

       public void Process()
       {
           string query = "something";
           // This method will be called in the Process method several times
           var data = _h.GetData(query);
       }
    }

    public interface IDataProvider 
    {
       IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString);
       DataTable FillDatatableFromAdapter(IDbCommand command);
    }

    public class DataProvider  : IDataProvider 
    {
         public IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
         {
             return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
         }

         public DataTable FillDatatableFromAdapter(IDbCommand command)
         {
              DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
              SqlCommand sqlCommand = command as SqlCommand;
              using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
              {
                  sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
              }

              if (dataSet.Tables.Count == 0)
                  return null;

              return dataSet.Tables[0];
         }
    }

public interface IHelper
{
     public DataTable GetData(string query);
}

public class Helper
{
   private readonly IDataProvider _dbProvider;
   public Helper(IDataProvider dbProvider)
   {
       _dbProvider = dbProvider;
   }

   public DataTable GetData(string query)
   { 
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       using (IDbConnection connection = 
       _databaseProvider.CreateConnection(_connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
           {
               command.CommandText = query;
               command.Connection = connection;
               table = _dbProvider.FillDatatableFromAdapter(command);
           }
       }
       return table;
    }   
}
```

Now you can have 4 isolated tests

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProccessFunctionCallHelperGetData()
    {
         Mock<IHelper> mockHelper = new Mock<IHelper>();
         Mock<IDataProvider> mockDatabaseProvider = new Mock<IDataProvider();

         mockHelper.Setup(m => m.getData(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new DataTable());
         MyApp app = new MyApp(mockDatabaseProvider.Object, mockHelper.Setup);
         app.Process();
         Assert.AreEquals(mockHelper.numTimesCalled, 1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestHelperGetData()
    {
        var query = ""; //TODO: write dummy query
        var dataTableToReturn = new DataTable(); //TODO: add some data
        Mock<IDataProvider> mockDatabaseProvider = new Mock<IDataProvider();
        mockDatabaseProvider.Setup(m => m.CreateConnection(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new SqlConnection("dummy connection string"));
        mockDatabaseProvider.Setup(m => m.FillDatatableFromAdapter(It.IsAny<IDbCommand>())).Returns(dataTableToReturn );

        IHelper h = new Helper(mockDatabaseProvider.Object);
        var actualDataTable = h.getData(query);
        Assert.AreEqual(dataTableToReturn, actualDataTable  );

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDataProviderFillDataTableFromAdapter()
    {
       //This test seems to me more like integration test because you need to mock a db or use a real db 
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestYourData()
    {
       // Create a dataTable with data so you can continue with your testing
    }
```